# How to display inputstream(image) to jsp in spring mvc?

Tags: spring-mvc, jsp, controller

I'm trying to display inpustream image which is on controller to JSP, without img folder.
Is there any direct way to display inpustream image to JSP?

Controller

```
SellerProduct criteria = beanMapper.map(product, SellerProduct.class);

    try {
        InputStream is=sardine.get(product.getProductImageUrl());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This is What I tried. But It requires webdav server login. So I'm trying to find other way

JSP

```
<!-- This is what I tried <td><img src="${f:h(SellerProduct.productImageUrl)}" height=50px width=50px></td> -->

<td>${f:h(SellerProduct.productYear)}</td>
              <td>${f:h(SellerProduct.productMonth)}</td>
              <td>${f:h(SellerProduct.productPrice)}</td>
              <td>${f:h(SellerProduct.productMake)}</td>
              <td>${f:h(SellerProduct.productMileage)}</td>
              <td>${f:h(SellerProduct.productEngine)}</td>
              <td>${f:h(SellerProduct.productFuel)}</td>
              <td>${f:h(SellerProduct.productTransmission)}</td>
```

Comment: What is the type of productImageUrl ?

Comment: Hi! that is model attribute, the ProductImageUrl is string